# Groovy way of null-checking constructor parameter

Tags: groovy

I want to inject non-null values into my groovy class

```
class MyClass {
    private final String foo
    private final Integer bar

    MyClass(String foo, Integer bar) {
        // wanted ctr body
    }
    ...
}
```

Within the constructor, I want to assign the params to the respective fields *AND* prevent null values.

I wonder if there is a groovier way of doing this than the quite verbose

```
assert foo != null
assert bar != null
this.foo = foo
this.bar = bar
```

or

```
this.foo = Objects.requireNonNull foo
this.bar = Objects.requireNonNull bar
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use Groovy 3, you can use [`@NullCheck`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/3.0.0/html/api/groovy/transform/NullCheck.html) annotation that adds defensive conditions constructor (or any methods) arguments.

```groovy
import groovy.transform.NullCheck

@NullCheck
class MyClass {
    private final String foo
    private final Integer bar

    MyClass(String foo, Integer bar) {
        this.foo = foo
        this.bar = bar
    }
}

// Examples:
new MyClass("test", null) // throws IllegalArgumentException("bar cannot be null")

new MyClass(null, "test") // throws IllegalArgumentException("foo cannot be null")
```

When you add `@NullCheck` on the class definition level, defensive null-check will be applied to all constructors and methods. Alternatively, you can add `@NullCheck` annotation to the methods (or constructors) you want to use this null-check only.

Before Groovy 3 such defensive checks have to be implemented manually.

Answer (score 1):

Only an important nuance, because the @NullCheck annotation only apply to **explicit** methods and constructos, as it is indicated in the official documentation.

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/gapi/groovy/transform/NullCheck.html

> If placed at the class level, all **explicit** methods and constructors will be checked.

If you are using other annotations as @TupleConstructor, all the **implicit** methods and constructors are not going to check parameters are not null.